# Linq - Take element with max datetime

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class :

```
public class Shop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

And one instance :

```
List<Shop> Shops = new List<Shop>()
{
    new Shop()
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2016, 08, 24),
        Name = "Shop1"
    },
     new Shop()
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2016, 08, 23),
        Name = "Shop2"
    },                new Shop()
    {
        Date = new DateTime(2016, 08, 22),
        Name = "Shop3"
    }
};
```

I want to take only shop with the max datetime. I do :

```
DateTime MaxDt = Shops.Max(x => x.Date);

Shop S = Shops.Where(x => x.Date == MaxDt).FirstOrDefault();
```

How to do this in one line ?

Comment: `MoreLINQ` has a [`.MaxBy`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) extension

Answer (score 3):

```
Shop S = Shops.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: a bit shorter `Shop S = Shops.OrderBy(x => x.Date).LastOrDefault();`